# ¿Porque la configurar Oh-My-Zsh a través sudo no surte efecto para el root?

Tags: linux, shell, debian, zsh

instale ZSH (sobre Debian) y lo configure tal y como lo indica [este enlace](https://conpilar.es/como-instalar-zsh-en-linux/).

El problema radica en que el usuario root solo tiene la forma básica de zsh, cuando intento instalar Oh-My-Zsh con el usuario root con la siguiente instrucción:

```
$ wget https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh -O - | zsh
```

y me indica que el directorio `$ZSH` existe y me sugiere tres opciones, pero de verdad no entiendo que debo hacer o lo que está pasando pues al usar el comando `sudo` no debería afectar a todo usuario incluido el root.

```sh
s10# wget https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh -O - | zsh
--2021-12-28 21:30:59--  https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh
Resolviendo github.com (github.com)... 140.82.112.3
Conectando con github.com (github.com)[140.82.112.3]:443... conectado.
Petición HTTP enviada, esperando respuesta... 301 Moved Permanently
Localización: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh [siguiendo]
--2021-12-28 21:31:06--  https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh
Reutilizando la conexión con github.com:443.
Petición HTTP enviada, esperando respuesta... 302 Found
Localización: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh [siguiendo]
--2021-12-28 21:31:06--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh
Resolviendo raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 185.199.108.133, 185.199.109.133, 185.199.111.133, ...
Conectando con raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)[185.199.108.133]:443... conectado.
Petición HTTP enviada, esperando respuesta... 200 OK
Longitud: 13399 (13K) [text/plain]
Grabando a: “STDOUT”

-                                         100%[====================================================================================>]  13,08K  --.-KB/s    en 0,1s    

2021-12-28 21:31:07 (121 KB/s) - escritos a stdout [13399/13399]

The $ZSH folder already exists (/home/juan/.oh-my-zsh).

You ran the installer with the $ZSH setting or the $ZSH variable is
exported. You have 3 options:

1. Unset the ZSH variable when calling the installer:
   `ZSH= sh install.sh`
2. Install Oh My Zsh to a directory that doesn't exist yet:
   `ZSH=path/to/new/ohmyzsh/folder sh install.sh`
3. (Caution) If the folder doesn't contain important information,
   you can just remove it with `rm -r /home/juan/.oh-my-zsh`
```

PD: pido disculpa si mi pregunta es muy superflua. :)

Comment: Bienvenido, Juan. Podrías reemplazar la imagen por texto copiado/pegado? Si no sabes ajustar el formato para que se vea como código, no te preocupes. Más de una persona estará encantada de modificar la pregunta para que se vea de la forma adecuada. Solo asegúrate de copiar/pegar el contenido dentro de la pregunta,.